# Double mathjax when asking

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, asking-questions, editor

I have been getting double mathjax recently when asking questions, and only when asking questions. It renders correctly on the preview but just makes my input box look weird. I use the latest version of chrome, and windows 10. Any known solutions to this?

Here is an example from when I was in the middle of writing a question.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache and restarting the browser?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yes, the problem still persists

Comment: Can I ask what browser (and version) and OS you are using? I can't repro locally, so I suspect it is specific to some combination...

Comment: Thanks, @suomynonA. That's odd as I can't reproduce this on latest Chrome and Win10 myself. Could there be a plugin interfering? Could you try it in incognito mode?

Comment: I tried it on incognito, and the problem is no longer there. I don't know which extension would be causing the problem though